# Should I assume doc file layout differences are not saved, just viewed?

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, libreoffice-writer, documents

If I open a doc file from environment A in environment B which results in differing layout and then edit and save it, should I assume those differences excluding deliberately edited parts will not be saved?

*I am using Libre Office. If there are any differences known between Microsoft Word, Libre Office, Open Office, etc., please state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I assume...

No, do not assume any such thing.  If you save the document, then there is a risk of causing either obvious or subtle changes.

This is especially true when using a different Office suite from that which created the document, but even different versions of the same suite, or even the same version in a different environment, may cause changes.

To avoid causing differences, it may be better to use PDF files instead, adding annotations.  Then the original author of the document can make changes to the .doc file.

There is a compilation of feature differences at [https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Feature_Comparison:*LibreOffice*-_Microsoft_Office](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Feature_Comparison:_LibreOffice_-_Microsoft_Office).

Comment: Looking around, there only seems to be similar comments.
It seems I should make the edits and let the other person make any layout adjustments if needed. If layout is very important and the other person is not going to make the adjustments, then PDF seems best(However, depending on circumstances original format might be important so sending both PDF and doc might be a good idea.).